# How to embed a file in html using jquery.load() in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to load a txt file using jquery in Chrome. Why it does not work? I have copied [this code snippet from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load), and all i have changed is their url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114993/how-to-embed-a-file-in-html-using-jquery-load");
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using ? do you get any javascript errors

Comment: @DominicGreen chrome on windows 8!

Comment: +1 @DominicGreen, It is cross browser issue! It works on firefox!

Comment: Does your `alert()` load?

Comment: Yep see my response bellow its to do with the cross origin domain policy and chrome being strict on running ajax localy

Comment: You can't use .load to get content from an external source due to the cross-origin policy unless the external source supports CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome throws the following error when executing your code:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You must:

1. Host your HTML code on your local web server, so that it is accessible at:

   `http://localhost/your_directory/index.html`
2. Update your code to load your `out.txt`, placed in the same folder where your `index.html` file is, like this (using relative paths)...

   `$("#div1").load("out.txt");`
3. ...or like this (using absolute paths):

   `$("#div1").load("http://localhost/your_directory/out.txt");`

And you are done! :-)

Comment: actually `$("#div1").load("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114993/how-to-embed-a-file-in-html-using-jquery-load");` also fails!

Comment: Sure it fails, what you tried is cross-origin AJAX, which is not allowed.  In any case, you must host your HTML file at your local web server as a start.  Then load with jQuery any file hosted ALSO at your local server.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue you are probably having here seems to happen allot with chrome and ajax requests. Chrome throws a security issue if running locally try putting your code on a web server, or try firefox.

Or if your on a mac you can open chrome using like this from the command line to prevent the security issue

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

There are loads of posts on google if your search for "allow file access from files chrome"

Good luck

Comment: So the user will also face the same problem. Right? :(

Comment: Only if they are running the file locally on the computer, I assume you will be hosting this web app on a server. Then there should be no problems.